# How to prevent multiple instance to get same couchbase document using CAS in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, couchbase

My requirement is to prevent multiple scheduler to get same document at same time. I have 3 scheduler instances.
So only 1 scheduler instance should be able to get/read document at same time.
I have obtained CAS value while reading document, but not sure how to use this CAS value to prevent other two scheduler to update that document.
Please suggest.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

CAS exists to protect against overwriting the document by multiple writers. What are you expecting to get? The server does not allow you to lock the key for reading.